# Angular - Validator on FormGroup breaks single validators on FormControl

Tags: angular, validation

I have a standard change password page, so you input your old password, then the new one and finally repeat the new one .

On the "`new password`" I have multiple custom validators, and I need one more to check if the "`new password`" is equal to the "`old password`".

But of course I cannot do that from `FormControl` because I don't have access to the "`old password`" `FormControl`, so I need to do the validation on `FormGroup`.

But what happens is, when it validates this part on `FormGroup`, then suddenly all validators on the "`new password`" `FormControl` are triggered!!

Is there a reason?

```
 this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        oldPassword: [
          "",
          {
            validators: [Validators.required],
        ],
        newPassword: [
          "",
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/\d/, { hasNumber: true }),
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]/, {
              hasCapitalCase: true,
            }),
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[a-z]/, { hasSmallCase: true }),
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(
              /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/,
              { hasSpecialCharacters: true }
            ),
            Validators.minLength(8),
          ]),
        ],
        confirmNewPassword: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      },
      { validators: [CustomValidators.passwordMatchValidator] }
    );
  }
```

my Custom `passwordMatchValidator`:

```
static passwordMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password: string = control.get("newPassword").value; 
    const confirmPassword: string = control.get("confirmNewPassword").value; 
    const oldPassword: string = control.get("oldPassword").value;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      control.get("confirmNewPassword").setErrors({ NoPassswordMatch: true });
    }

    if (password === oldPassword) {

   control.get("newPassword").setErrors({ OldPasswordMatch: true });
  }
  }
```

so basically, if this FormGroup validator triggers the "`OldPasswordMatch`" error, then suddenly, all the specific Validators on `newPassword` FormControl will get triggered, why is that?

I cannot put this validation on the `FormControl` "`new password`" because it has no access to the `FormControl` "`old password`"

Comment: not sure what you're trying to say here. all validators on a form control / group are evaluated all the time unless you set a different `updateOn` option. regardless of what you're doing at the form group level.  if a form control is marked as required, if it has no value, it will be marked as invalid and as having a required error no matter what

Comment: what I'm telling you is, until I add the second part on passwordMatchValidator (the one that checks password === oldPassword) all works fine, as soon as that is added, whenever those 2 password matches, not only that Validation error will trigger, but also all errors from the FormControl validation above, so for example the Validators.minLength(8) will trigger, even if the matching password have only 2 characters!! why is this happening?

Comment: it's triggering because your password only has 2 characters and the minlength is 8??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you're saying regarding "all validators triggering" as they all validate all the time, but regardless, you're not implementing a group level validator correctly. validators shouldn't access controls and set errors, they return null or an error object... as it's a group level validator, it should be more like:

```
static passwordMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password: string = control.get("newPassword").value; 
    const confirmPassword: string = control.get("confirmNewPassword").value; 
    const oldPassword: string = control.get("oldPassword").value;

    let errors = null;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      errors = { NoPassswordMatch: true };
    }

    if (password === oldPassword) {
      errors = Object.assign(errors || {}, { OldPasswordMatch: true });
    }

    return errors;
}
```

then this error will appear on the group. and you need to take that into account in your template / user prompts.

to make your inputs aware of the error with angular material, you must implement an `ErrorStateMatcher`:

```
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class GroupErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {

  constructor(private checkError: string) {}

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const groupError = form && form.hasError(this.checkError);
    return !!(control && (control.invalid || groupError) && (control.dirty || control.touched));
  }
}
```

use in component:

```
oldPasswordMatch =  new GroupErrorStateMatcher('OldPasswordMatch')
noPasswordMatch =  new GroupErrorStateMatcher('NoPassswordMatch')
```

which you attach to the respective inputs:

```
<input matInput [errorStateMatcher]="oldPasswordMatch" formControlName="newPassword">

<input matInput [errorStateMatcher]="noPasswordMatch" formControlName="confirmNewPassword">
```

Comment: I mean sorry, they will NOT trigger, I said the contrary! do you see all the validators on the FormControl called "newPassword" right? for example, the validator: hasNumber, will trigger if there is NO number ok? Now, as soon as I add the second code block in passwordMatchValidator, the one that starts with if (password ===oldPassword), now suddenly, whenever this error is triggered, ALL FormControls error for "new password" won't trigger anymore, EVEN if for example, the password is "test" and oldPassoword is "test", so there are errors, like Min length is not 8 and there are no numbers

Comment: That makes more sense. The problem is that you’re overwriting them when you call setErrors.. which is part of why you don’t want to do that

Comment: ok I see that makes sense, but then how can I manage this? your solution sadly doesnt work, am I missing something? myForm doesnt get those errors (i have a console log to show all errors for the form)

Comment: I prepared a stackblitz for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opqvdi

Comment: there you can see what I mean, first you should comment out line 33 to 35 of custom-validator component, then you can see everything works fine, but if you uncomment those lines, and try to put in the first input box "string", then in the second box "string", you ll see that ALL validation rules for the second input are discarded!

Comment: can you help me with that stackblitz to find a working solution? the last check I need to implement (line 33-35) is to check that the user didnt put as "new password" the same old password!

Comment: i also made a blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dct2jc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: in your blitz, you're still checking the CONTROLS. you MUST check the GROUP... do this: `myForm.hasError('NoPassswordMatch')` NOT this: `myForm.controls['confirmNewPassword'].hasError('NoPassswordMatch')` ... GROUP level errors appear on the GROUP

Comment: ok but how can I apply the errors on the Control direclty? I prefer that way instead of the group, because if the error is on the control, then the FormField will "know" there is an error (the input will be red and so on), while this does not happen if there is a "generic" error on the group level! Is it possible to implement that Validation direclty on the Control in my solution?

Comment: group level errors belong on the group. you just fix your template to be aware of group level errors. This is why angular material provides things like `ErrorStateMatcher`

Comment: sorry I didnt understand what do you mean, how can I make it, with your solution, that when the error triggers (the one for Old passwrd = new password) , I visually see the FormField input becomes red like it does with the validations done directly on the control?

Comment: you rewrite your template to show error states when group level errors are present....

Comment: that is clear, I know I can make messages appear with ngIf and check if the error is there. That part is ok, but I'm missing how can I also get the FormField of the specific Control show visually the error by becoming red and without having to create classes and use ngClass? I hope I explained myself sorry

Comment: you use an `ErrorStateMatcher` if you're using angular material. if you're using some other library or your own code, you need some interface like the `ErrorStateMatcher`

Comment: yes I m using angular material, could I ask you for a small example on how implement this ErrorStateMatcher? anyway, thank you for your kindness and all the informations you gave me

Comment: added an example of a matcher. can be customized however you need it to work.